# How can I merge a development site with a production one on an earlier core version?

Tags: 6, migrations

I work for a small company that currently has a Drupal 6 site setup and working well on a live Azure server. However, we need to migrate to D8 (should have done it years ago!) and are wondering how to manage this.

We have gotten so far as working out how to migrate the current config and content to D8 through use of the migrate tools, migrate plus and migrate manifest modules. But we're now wondering how to combine this with a database merge from our D8 dev DB to the live D6 DB.

It would obviously be a disaster if users were suddenly unable to login anymore, or if their content suddenly disappeared. So we're looking for the safest, but ideally fastest and most-integrated solution, i.e. if we could go from D6 prod straight to D8 prod using the D8 dev data, that would be ideal. I imagine this would be impossible though, and that a D6 to D8 migration would have to be performed on the live site before anything else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for a module recommendation, as listed in the _refrain from asking_ section in the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Instead, please describe how you've tried to solve the problem, and provide details of where you're stuck.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I *did* explain what we've tried: "We have gotten so far as working out how to migrate the current config and content to D8 through use of the migrate tools, migrate plus and migrate manifest modules". We did this is a dev environment though, and we're worried that performing the process on the live server could cause problems. If someone who has done this or something similar could explain *how* they did so, that is all we really need.

Comment: But the question is _Are there any (preferably D6) modules that can facilitate this kind of workflow?_ which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno LMAO, so if I hadn't included that simple sentence in my question, you wouldn't have closed it?? Don't you think that's being kinda anal?? It doesn't necessarily **have** to be a module, just any method of doing this would be fine!

Comment: Yeah it's literally that simple @Kenny83, anal or not :) If you ask for module recommendations, it's off topic; the majority of the time when you remove that one line, _are there any modules that do what I want?_, the question fails to stand on its own any more (i.e. usually, asking for modules is a good indicator of a not great question). Having read it, yours is obviously an exception to that, so thanks for editing and I think re-opening is the right thing to do now